# Trying to duplicate a table image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to duplicate a table image using HTML but have no idea how to begin.

[image]

I feel like I should just start with something like

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table Example</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Table cell(th)</th>
    <th>In bold</th>
    <th>centered</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell(td)</td>
    <td>Text - Row 2 - cell 2 (td)</td>
    <td>Text - Row 2 - cell 3 (td)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text - Row 3 - cell 1</td>
    <td>Text - Row 3 - cell 2</td>
    <td>Text - Row 3 - cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and then expand from there. Any help on how to get a solid foundation started for this would be great, as well with how to color those different words with various background colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this, its pretty similar :)

```css
.tg  {
 border-spacing: 15px;
}
.tg td {
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 background: #32CC98;
}
.tg th {
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:10px 5px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-break:normal;
 background: #32CC98;
}
.tg .tedelarge {
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle
}
.tg .tede {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
 <tr>
  <th class="tede">The</th>
  <th class="tede">Little</th>
  <th class="tede">Piggy</th>
  <th class="tede">Went</th>
  <th class="tede">To</th>
  <th class="tede">Market</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tede" colspan="2">This</td>
  <td class="tede">Little</td>
  <td class="tede">Piggy</td>
  <td class="tede">Went</td>
  <td class="tede">To</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tede" colspan="4">This</td>
  <td class="tedelarge" rowspan="3">Little</td>
  <td class="tede">Piggy</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tede" rowspan="2">This</td>
  <td class="tede">Little</td>
  <td class="tede">Piggy</td>
  <td class="tede">Went</td>
  <td class="tede">To</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tede">Little</td>
  <td class="tede">Piggy</td>
  <td class="tede">Went</td>
  <td class="tede">To</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```